# FInite additivity of measures implies countable super-additivity

Tags: measure-theory

There are plenty of counter examples proving that finite additivity does not always imply countable additivity and I have well understood why. However, it does imply countable super additivity. I am unable to prove this property of finitely additive measures as no other property of these measures mention using limits (probably needed to make the finite to countable jump?). Any hints for this proof please?

Comment: I wanted to give a hint at first but it would have been the whole solution just summed up in fewer words, so hopefully you'll excuse me writing the answer in full.

Comment: @BrunoB thank you for your help, really!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\mu$ be a finitely-additive positive measure (also known as "content") on a ring of sets $\mathcal{A}$.
Let $(A_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \in \mathcal{A}$ be a sequence of pairwise disjoint sets, and take $A := \bigcup_{i = 1}^\infty A_i$, $B_n := \bigcup_{i = 1}^n A_i$, and $C_n := \bigcup_{i = n + 1}^\infty A_i$.
Because $B_n \cup C_n = A$ and $B_n$ and $C_n$ are disjoint, we have:
$$\mu(A) = \mu(B_n) + \mu(C_n) \geq \mu(B_n) = \sum_{i = 1}^n \mu(A_i)$$
Since this is true for all $n$, we obtain:
$$\mu(A) \geq \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \,\,\sum_{i = 1}^n \mu(A_i) = \sum_{i = 1}^\infty \mu(A_i)$$
with the last equality being true because the sequence $\left(\sum_{i = 1}^n \mu(A_i)\right)_n$ is increasing.
Thus $\mu$ is indeed $\sigma$-superadditive.